# Compilation error for multi threaded programs compiled using riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc

Tags: riscv

```
/* Includes */
#include <unistd.h>     /* Symbolic Constants */
#include <sys/types.h>  /* Primitive System Data Types */ 
#include <errno.h>      /* Errors */
#include <stdio.h>      /* Input/Output */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* General Utilities */
#include <pthread.h>    /* POSIX Threads */
#include <string.h>     /* String handling */

/* prototype for thread routine */
void print_message_function ( void *ptr );

/* struct to hold data to be passed to a thread
   this shows how multiple data items can be passed to a thread */
typedef struct str_thdata
{
    int thread_no;
    char message[100];
} thdata;

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;  /* thread variables */
    thdata data1, data2;         /* structs to be passed to threads */

    /* initialize data to pass to thread 1 */
    data1.thread_no = 1;
    strcpy(data1.message, "Hello!");

    /* initialize data to pass to thread 2 */
    data2.thread_no = 2;
    strcpy(data2.message, "Hi!");

    /* create threads 1 and 2 */    
    pthread_create (&thread1, NULL, (void *) &print_message_function, (void *) &data1);
    pthread_create (&thread2, NULL, (void *) &print_message_function, (void *) &data2);

    /* Main block now waits for both threads to terminate, before it exits
       If main block exits, both threads exit, even if the threads have not
       finished their work */ 
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    /* exit */  
    exit(0);
} /* main() */

/**
 * print_message_function is used as the start routine for the threads used
 * it accepts a void pointer 
**/
void print_message_function ( void *ptr )
{
    thdata *data;            
    data = (thdata *) ptr;  /* type cast to a pointer to thdata */

    /* do the work */
    printf("Thread %d says %s \n", data->thread_no, data->message);

    pthread_exit(0); /* exit */
} /* print_message_function ( void *ptr ) */
```

The error that i faced was
thread-ex.c:24:5: error: unknown type name 'pthread_t'
     pthread_t thread1, thread2;  /* thread variables */
     ^
thread-ex.c:36:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_create' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     pthread_create (&thread1, NULL, (void *) &print_message_function, (void *) &data1);
     ^
thread-ex.c:42:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_join' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
     ^
thread-ex.c: In function 'print_message_function':
thread-ex.c:61:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_exit' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     pthread_exit(0); /* exit */

Comment: I wanted to create 2 threads and simulate spike in the multicore mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pthreads are not available with the newlib based RISC-V compiler. You will need to use the linux based RISC-V compiler (riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc). You can find instructions to build and install the linux based compiler at the same riscv-gcc repo (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain).

Comment: If i build with riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc will spike be able to run it

Comment: Yes, but you will need to run it on riscv-linux and not pk.

Comment: How do i run it on risk linux??? what is the syntax??? Im working with the zed board, do i need to boot risk-linux on the board and then run the binary on that. If there is a syntax explaining the same. Please help me

Comment: Yes, you will need to place your binary in a linux disk image, boot linux on the board, and then run your binary from within linux.

Comment: OK but the riscv-linux for zedboard does not even come with GCC... How do I run the binary on it??

Comment: You need gcc to build your binary, not to run it. As stated above, build your binary with riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc, copy that into the disk image, then executed your binary (already cross-compiled).